# How can I interact with my custom keyboard from Xamarin UITest?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitest, xamarin.uitest

I am trying out Xamarin.UITest on iOS, and I am running into the problem that I cannot scroll in my custom `UIPickerView` keyboard.

So my question is: if I have a `UIPickerView` as a keyboard, how can I select a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply perform `.Invoke("selectRow", 3 , "inComponent", 3, "animated", true)` on your `UIPickerView` to execute the method `picker.SelectRow(3, 3, true)`.

Full statement:

```
app.Query(e => e.Id("MyUIPickerId").Invoke("selectRow", 3 , "inComponent", 3, "animated", true));
```